# Minimal Kiosk Browser not working with xinit on boot

Tags: linux, boot, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem with a booting sequence in my Raspberry Pi.
My goal is to have a Minimal Kiosk Browser (kweb) run in a boot sequence. 
To do that, I made changes in script /etc/rc.local:

```
(...)
sh /home/lustron/Lustron/starter.sh   &
sleep 5s
python /home/lustron/Lustron/sensor5.py  &


exit 0
```

and the starter.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xinit /usr/bin/kweb -KHCUA+-zbhrqfpoklgtjneduwxy file:///var/www/index.php &
```

Unfortunately, when my RPi boots, it ends on a command line of user Lustron, like it wasn't using the /etc/rc.local file at all. 
When I am executing the command `sudo sh /etc/rc/local`, the script is booting and I can see the xserver starts, but there is only a white "window?" on a 3/4 part of a screen. The only error I can see is: `FATAL: module g2d_23 not found`
The other script (sensor5.py) is working fine.

What is the problem here? 
Obviously there are two issues here: 
- xinit not initialized properly
- /etc/rc.local not being executed on boot

Comment: You might consider using [`nodm`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=nodm) to serve as a no-frills autologin display manager. IMO it's better than running X directly because it goes through setting up proper X session as it would be created using "normal" way (a user logging via GDB or whatnot) -- just automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `/etc/rc.local` is executable (`chmod a+rx`). You can add to the start a line to redirect errors to a logfile:

```
exec 2>>/tmp/rc.errors
```

There are several Virtual Terminals in linux. Only 1 can appear on the screen at a time. The X11 server uses a VT too. File `/etc/inittab` has a line for each VT like this eg:

```
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
```

You may want to suppress these later on when things are working. You can change between VTs from the keyboard with <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> for example to get to VT 7 (tty7) which is usually the only one left not used
by `getty` (from the inittab), and so the one the X11 server will be on.

You can also use the `chvt` command (as root) to change VT.

Comment: So `chmod a+rx` helped with the rc.local issue and now, all scripts are running at the boot sequence. The problem still exists on the xinit side, but maybe I should add a window manager? I tried with matchbox-window-manager, but it didn't work. The thing is, I don't want to use keyboard for this. I want to automaticize this process: to boot and open websitesite in php in kiosk mode browser.

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution from: http://blogs.wcode.org/2013/09/howto-boot-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-fullscreen-browser-kiosk/

I added the following to the /etc/rc.local:

```
if [ -f /boot/xinitrc ]; then
    ln -fs /boot/xinitrc /home/pi/.xinitrc;
    su - pi -c 'startx' &
fi
```

and to the /boot/xinitrc:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do

    # Clean up previously running apps, gracefully at first then harshly
    killall -TERM chromium 2>/dev/null;
    killall -TERM matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;
    sleep 2;
    killall -9 chromium 2>/dev/null;
    killall -9 matchbox-window-manager 2>/dev/null;

    # Clean out existing profile information
    rm -rf /home/pi/.cache;
    rm -rf /home/pi/.config;
    rm -rf /home/pi/.pki;

    # Generate the bare minimum to keep Chromium happy!
    mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default
    sqlite3 /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Web\ Data "CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR); INSERT INTO meta VALUES('version','46'); CREATE TABLE keywords (foo INTEGER);";

    # Disable DPMS / Screen blanking
    xset -dpms
    xset s off

    # Reset the framebuffer's colour-depth
    fbset -depth $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbdepth );

    # Hide the cursor (move it to the bottom-right, comment out if you want mouse interaction)
    xwit -root -warp $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbwidth ) $( cat /sys/module/*fb*/parameters/fbheight )

    # Start the window manager (remove "-use_cursor no" if you actually want mouse interaction)
    matchbox-window-manager -use_titlebar no -use_cursor no &

    # Start the browser (See http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
    chromium  --app=http://URL.of.your/choice.html

done;
```